# Display items in columns with ability to break them

Tags: html, css, display

Is there a way to display items in columns with ability to break them? Like in the picture below

[image]

These items consist of divs and the way it was displayed before was display: contents.
But now I need to add some styles to the item and with display: contents it is not possible (I need to add a colored border). So I wonder if there is another way to display itesm in columns with abitily for each item to be broken into two or more columns.

Here is the example of the structure we have now with .parent having display: contents property. I need to get rid of it but still save the column layout with items breaking into columns.

https://codepen.io/olga4irkova/pen/RwxrVqB

``

```
`<div id='field'>
  <div class='parent'>
    <div class='item'>Start</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
   <div class='item'>End</div>
 </div>

 <div class='parent'>
    <div class='empty'></div>
    <div class='item'>Start</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>End</div>
 </div>

 <div class='parent'>
    <div class='empty'></div>
    <div class='item'>Start</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>End</div>
 </div>

 <div class='parent'>
    <div class='empty'></div>
    <div class='item'>Start</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>Item</div>
    <div class='item'>End</div>
 </div>
</div>`


`#field {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: baseline;
  max-height: 250px;
}

.parent {
  display: contents;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 10px;
}

.empty {
  height: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: green;
  width: 30%; 
  height: 10px; 
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}`
```

Comment: Check out this tutorial on grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids

Comment: It's very unclear what your items contain. What does the HTML look like? It's possible, that [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) could be what you want, but without more information it's difficult to say.

Comment: items consist of divs under one another

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

```
#field {
   columns: 6;
}

.parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.empty {
  height: 10px;
}

.item {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

(I removed most of the hard-coded `height`s/`width`s, because they break the layout and are generally a bad idea, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is called a Masonry layout. It can be achieved by using CSS Grids as explained here https://www.smashingmagazine.com/native-css-masonry-layout-css-grid/

Comment: as far as I understand items cannot be broken if we use this method

Comment: add grid-gap: yourValue;

Comment: I mean one item should be broken and displayed in column one and in column two if it isi too long and does not fit the page

Comment: this didn't work becaue I need items to be broken and to several columns